# Can an F# replace an A?

Tags: scales, chord-theory, chord-progressions, bass-guitar

I play the bass in a band. We are playing Ray LaMontagne's "A Falling Through."   The chords for the intro and verses are C/G and F, but our guitarist prefers playing C  Cmaj7  Am and F.  The problem is that the A sounds out of place in that progression on the bass.  Any ideas on how to resolve this?  I have tried two options that sound OK:  (1) Ignoring the Am and simply playing an C and F, or (2) replacing the A with its 5th (F#).  Better ideas from more experienced bassists out there?  Thanks.

Comment: The fifth of A isn't F# - it's E.

Comment: randy H. if you're not so confident with note names it's OK to give fret numbers in the question too, then we can correct any mistakes :)

Comment: Also disagree about the C/G. The bass first plays C, so the chord cannot be 'slash G'.

Answer (score 4):

First you should decide if you don't want to stick to the original. The intro is pretty dominated by this bass melody:

```
X: 1
M: C
K: Cmaj
L: 1/8
V:C name="Bass" clef=bass-8
c,,3 g,, b,,c,b,,c, | f,,3 f,, b,,c,b,,c, | c,,3 g,, b,,c,b,,c, | f,,3 a,, b,,c,d,c, :|
```

That would still fit pretty well over `C - Cmaj7 | am - F` – the `am` would actually be `am/F` which is equivalent to `Fmaj7` and the `F` would rather be something like `b7♭5`, which may look weird but is actually not unreasonable harmonically (the latter fulfilling a bit of a dominant role).

Playing an **A** or even **F♯** is certainly also possible, but both would lead to a sound that's significantly different from the original's “cotton wool country” feeling, **A** pointing more towards folk/rock and **F♯** more toward jazz. Only you and the band can decide whether that's what you want.

Comment: +1 for half-dim reference. Also good to note that relative major/minor's can be used as substitution because of their common tones. As long as the band covers those common tones, playing an F# should be fine. It will sound a little different but with added flavor.